# Canvas - Path looks like zoomed in

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a bezier path on a canvas. Although the canvas is wide enough the path does not fit into it. It looks as if the path was zoomed in. What is wrong?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bdfbznx/)

JS

```
var canvas, context;

init();

function init() {

 canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


context = canvas.getContext("2d");



context.fillStyle = 'rgb(245,245,245)';
context.fillRect( 0, 0, 420, 256 );

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 70);

context.bezierCurveTo(160, 50, 240, 50, 400, 50);
context.lineWidth=4;
context.stroke();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the width and height attributes on the canvas element. Right now you have a canvas of default size, which is scaled be css, that's why it looks zoomed.

```
<canvas width="440" height="256" ></canvas>
```